# Issues with Fetching the data from database

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I can fetch the data like this.

```
value= mymodel.objects.get(anycondition)
```

**OR**

```
value= mymodel.objects.filter(anycondition)
```

and can send them to my template with context.

But if I want to select all the data from a table(for all users not only one) as this query does

```
value= mymodel.objects.all()
```

and send this value to my template and can see there field by field

e.g.

my table has two fields name and phone no and I use the above query(    **value= mymodel.objects.all()**) now if i want to see all names then i can see that and if i want to see phone no. I can see that too.

I have tried this and it doesn't work and I even I do not know it is possible or not.
If it is possible then please let me know how I can do this ?

I hope you understand my question. !!

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, sorry, don't understand at all. There's no difference in the structure of the data sent by `filter(foo=bar)` and `all()`, except of course that the second one sends all the data.

Comment: do you need to loop over the objects and display each attribute?  eg `{% for obj in all_objects %} {{ obj.name }} {{ obj.phone_no }} {% endfor %}`

Comment: I have no idea what you want. You're telling everything works "i can see" and "i can see that too" - but then saying "it doesn't work". WHAT does not work?

Comment: and I am editing my question ....... which let you know what I am doing and what I am getting

Comment: @hwjp   You got my question ..... and what It works !!!!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.all()` will return a ***list*** of objects that represent the rows in your model. `.get()` only returns one object. Your template is trying to print the result of `all()` if it was one object.

This is the same as if you had a list and you wanted to loop through it. In your view you would do:

```
product = Product_attributes.objects.all()
for i in product:
   print i.size
   print i.color
```

The equvalent for the template is:

```
<ul>
{% for i in product %}
   <li>{{ i.size }}</li>
   <li>{{ i.color }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Umm, what? This is a different question entirely. Looks like you need [model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: I just used the **input type="text"** and inside **name** i used **{{item.id}}** and it takes the different name for each record so i think i got what i want.... *again thanks for your interest*

Answer (score 0):

Although this question isn't clear it seems like you are having a bit of problem with Field Lookups. It is fairly easy to learn [Here is a link to get you started](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups)

Comment: ok so I asked a simple question.I have a table of Three fields(id,col1,col2) now i wants to display all the data in col3 into my template then how i can do that??